# Italics makes the text appear twice

Tags: fonts

I am writing a document with some big quotes. But i want the quotes to be italics, but when i use the \emph command it appears twice for some reason i cant figure out.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\begin{document}


hey, example of emph with quote 

\begin{quote}
\emph{
    "Jf. BR18, kap. 1, § 21, skal der ved ansøgning om byggetilladelse til byggeri i brandklasse 2 være
tilknyttet en brandrådgiver, der er certificeret til at virke i brandklasse 2. Brandrådgiveren, der
har de kompetencer, der er nødvendige for at udarbejde og kontrollere den brandtekniske
dokumentation for byggeri i brandklasse 2, må således jf. BR18 kap. 27, § 493 stå for
brandsikringen af et byggeri, hvis: \\

De brandsikringstekniske løsninger udføres i overensstemmelse med de præ-accepterede
løsninger, som er beskrevet i denne vejlednings bilag 1 – 10, eller der er tale om
Bygningsafsnit, der grundlæggende opfylder kravene for brandklasse 1, men hvor der
anvendes præ-accepterede løsninger for brug af brandtekniske installationer udover
simple anlæg som røgalarmanlæg, brandslukningsmateriel mv.
De præ-accepterede løsninger i denne vejlednings bilag 1 – 10 udgør dimensionerings- og
dokumentationsgrundlaget for byggeri i brandklasse 2.}

\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Do you know whats going on?

Comment: If the text appears twice that is due to code you have not shown, Please always post a complete small document that shows the problem, not a fragment that can not be run/debugged.

Comment: I'd use `\em` or `\itshape` for a multi-paragraph italic rather than `\emph` with the text in an argument, but the text should not appear twice in any case.

Comment: I dont have either \em or \itshape in my commands?
And this is my code, i dont know what else to give you.

```

Comment: You should give a (small) *complete* example. One starting with \documentclass and ending with \end{document}, so that we can compile and look if we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: you need ti give us an example that we can run that shows the problem, it should start `\documentclass` end `\end{document}` and show some text being typeset twice. If your text is appearing twice perhaps you have `\renewcommand\emph[1]{#1 #1}` and the answer is "don't do that" but without seeing what is causing the problem we can't say what to change,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i have edited my post to show the preamble.

Comment: @MortenMandsberg that is already helpful, but it is not yet sufficient to reproduce your problem. That makes it more difficult for us to see what the issue might be. The question would improve if you make your example compilable, i.e., if we copy-paste the code without any changes and run LaTeX it should produce a document where the quote is printed two times. This also means it should not include any images, citations etc. that we do not have. Furthermore it should be as small as possible, so remove any packages, settings etc. that do not affect the issue.

Comment: No. if you want someone to say why the problem occurs you need to provide an example that reproduces the problem. We can not debug code that you have not shown.

Comment: I have once again edited to show the bare minimum of a new document, and the problem still occurs. I know its another language but you can see that it repeats the same words after my \\

Comment: If you get an error, please ask about the _error_ not about the typeset output (which is not intended to be usable after an error)

Answer (score 2):

You get an error

```
! Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.
```

after any error the pdf output is not intended for use just for possible debugging, use `\em` as suggested in comments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\begin{document}


hey, example of emph with quote 

\begin{quote}
\em
    "Jf. BR18, kap. 1, § 21, skal der ved ansøgning om byggetilladelse til byggeri i brandklasse 2 være
tilknyttet en brandrådgiver, der er certificeret til at virke i brandklasse 2. Brandrådgiveren, der
har de kompetencer, der er nødvendige for at udarbejde og kontrollere den brandtekniske
dokumentation for byggeri i brandklasse 2, må således jf. BR18 kap. 27, § 493 stå for
brandsikringen af et byggeri, hvis: 

De brandsikringstekniske løsninger udføres i overensstemmelse med de præ-accepterede
løsninger, som er beskrevet i denne vejlednings bilag 1 – 10, eller der er tale om
Bygningsafsnit, der grundlæggende opfylder kravene for brandklasse 1, men hvor der
anvendes præ-accepterede løsninger for brug af brandtekniske installationer udover
simple anlæg som røgalarmanlæg, brandslukningsmateriel mv.
De præ-accepterede løsninger i denne vejlednings bilag 1 – 10 udgør dimensionerings- og
dokumentationsgrundlaget for byggeri i brandklasse 2.

\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Note `\\` should never be used at the end of a paragraph, LaTeX warns

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 10--15
```

where 10000 is the *maximum* level of how bad its measure of the typesetting is. I removed the `\\` here.

Comment: I still dont know what the error was, but using \em worked. thanks!

And thanks for the headsup on the end of paragraph thing.

Comment: The error is that commands like `\emph` are intended for short runs of text they can not have a paragraph break in the argument. @MortenMandsberg

Comment: Perfekt, thanks!